# PowerQuery importing csv Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Table

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to import data from a comma delimited text file using the below code

```
let
Source = Folder.Files("\\alignefsxprd.aws.edfenergy.net\share\ETRMHUB\Lookup\Config"),
FilteredFiles = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "hedge_factors_config_")),
MaxDateModified = List.Max(FilteredFiles[Date modified]),
FilteredFilesMaxDate = Table.SelectRows(FilteredFiles, each [Date modified] =  MaxDateModified),
 ImportData = Table.Combine(
        List.Transform(FilteredFilesMaxDate[Content], each Csv.Document(_, [Delimiter=",", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]){0})
    )
in
    ImportData
```

But get the following error

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Record to type Table.
Details:
    Value=
        Column1=TEAM_FILE
        Column2=EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATETIME
        Column3=EFFECTIVE_TO_DATETIME
        Column4=BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_3
        Column5=BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_6
        Column6=BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_8
        Column7=FORECAST_BOOk
```

First few lines of the .csv look like this

```
TEAM_FILE,EFFECTIVE_FROM_DATETIME,EFFECTIVE_TO_DATETIME,BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_3,BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_6,BOOK_ATTRIBUTE_8,FORECAST_BOOK,HEDGE_BOOK,TARGET_BOOK,TRADE_GROUP_1,FACTOR_START,FACTOR_END,STRATEGY_TYPE,CARBON_TRADES,AVERAGED,MATRIX_FILE,ALIGNE_DATE,TARGET_DATE,TARGET_FACTOR,VOLUME_HEDGE
B2C,27/04/2022,31/12/2022,POWER,B2C,RES,PREF,PREH,PRET,PROGRESSIVE 6_2_6,01/06/2023,30/06/2023,Passthrough,,,,,,1,
B2C,27/04/2022,31/12/2022,POWER,B2C,RES,PREF,PREH,PRET,PROGRESSIVE 6_2_6,01/07/2023,31/07/2023,Passthrough,,,,,,1,
B2C,27/04/2022,31/12/2022,POWER,B2C,RES,PREF,PREH,PRET,PROGRESSIVE 6_2_6,01/08/2023,31/08/2023,Passthrough,,,,,,0.9,
B2C,27/04/2022,31/12/2022,POWER,B2C,RES,PREF,PREH,PRET,PROGRESSIVE 6_2_6,01/09/2023,30/09/2023,Passthrough,,,,,,0.9,
```

Is the issue the space in the first line forecast book column (in the middle of this)? 'PROGRESSIVE 6_2_6'

Answer (score 0):

```
let Source = Folder.Files("\\alignefsxprd.aws.edfenergy.net\share\ETRMHUB\Lookup\Config"),
FilteredFiles = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "hedge_factors_config_")),
MaxDateModified = List.Max(FilteredFiles[Date modified]),
FilteredFilesMaxDate = Table.SelectRows(FilteredFiles, each [Date modified] =  MaxDateModified),
#"Added CSVdata" = Table.AddColumn(FilteredFilesMaxDate, "CSVdata", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content])), type table),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added CSVdata", "Custom", each let name = [Name] in Table.AddColumn([CSVdata],"SourceFile", each name)),
#"Combined CSVdata" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom])
in #"Combined CSVdata"
```